# Receber a altura errada do header

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

Estou a tentar apanhar a altura do `.ui-header` para poder ter o meu programa dinâmico.
Acontece que a altura que me está a dar está incorrecta.

O código para apanhar a altura do `.ui-header`:

```
//Altura do header
        var lv_headerHeight =  $(".ui-header").outerHeight();
        alert("HEADER " + lv_headerHeight);
```

Esse `alert` está a returnar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas usando as ferramentas de dev do Chrome, indica que a altura do `.ui-header` é: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que consigo apanhar este ultimo valor? 
Obrigado pela atenção

Ou seja, tenho este header:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O alert está a dar-me um valor incorrecto da sua altura enquanto o Chrome dev tools dá-me o valor correcto. Mas não estou a conseguir apanha-lo

Comment: Acho que é necessário mais informações, existe alguma animação acontecendo no elemento? o resultado é compatível com a altura do elemneto no momento em que o alert é chamado? em um exemplo simples, funciona como o esperado http://jsfiddle.net/4o17h3xe/

Comment: Não existe nenhuma animação. Eu pensei em tentar passar o problema para o fiddle, mas estou a usar o jquery-ui e acho que no fiddle não tem disso.

Comment: nem um slidedown? digo isso porque pelo print a class do elemento cita um slide down que poderia estar acontecendo. edit, vi agora seu comentário atualizado, um exemplo de fiddle usando ui http://jsfiddle.net/xBB5x/2511/

Comment: Acredito que esse slidedown é imposto pela UI ou algo do genero, pois tive agora a percorrer o código e não tenho nada daquilo

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim, irá pegar as coordenadas X/Y do ponto esquerdo/topo:

```
img = document.getElementById('box');
imagemTopRightX = img.offsetLeft;
imagemTopRightY = img.offsetTop;
alert(imagemTopRightX);
alert(imagemTopRightY);
```